# Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'Project1' in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, eclipse-cdt

When a project (Project1) is imported , the below error is thrown. 
I am using Eclipse Mars as IDE and the product is an eclipse RCP product.
"org.eclipse.core.resources" as well as "org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core" are added in the plugin dependencies.

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2017-01-03 14:16:08.869
    !MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core 4 75 2017-01-03 14:16:08.869
    !MESSAGE Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'Project1'.  
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:478)
        at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Can someone help me here ??